# Updating slug with mongoose .pre('save')

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So i've scoured everywhere and I cannot for the love of me figure out what is wrong! Im working on a webapp that requires blog posts and the slug is directly tied to the name of the article(including some regex). But when updating the posting everything changes besides the slug! So the url params still show the old slug instead of the new one. Any thoughts?

```
 const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: 'Please enter an article name'
        },
    slug: String,
    description:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: 'Please enter an description'
    },
    content:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: 'Please enter article content'
        },
    tags: [String],
    created:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    photo: String
})


articleSchema.pre('save', async function(next){
    try{
        if(!this.isModified('name')){
            next()
            return;
        }

       this.slug = slug(this.name)

    const slugRegEx = new RegExp(`^(${this.slug})((-[0-9]*$)?)$`,'i')

    const articlesWithSlug = await this.constructor.find({slug: 
slugRegEx})

    if(articlesWithSlug.length){
      this.slug = `${this.slug}-${articlesWithSlug.length + 1}`
 }
  next()
    }catch(error){
        throw error
    }
})
```

Comment: You missed an important detail. How do you update? Edit your question with sample code. Add `console.log()` statements in your `pre` middleware, and see whether it gets called when you update.

Answer (score 2):

You need one of `update`, `updateOne`, `updateMany`,  or `findOneAndUpdate` pre hooks depending on what operation you are using.

But `this` will not point to the document in such hook, as it does in the pre-save, you will need to modify update query instead.

You can get query object by `this.getUpdate()`

Since all the hooks for update operations work similar, you can register a single function to handle all of them.
Here is an [example how I did it](https://github.com/YuriGor/mongoose-slug-updater/blob/70fd9fa214ce179d69d9687ac6af32ba1b83db08/lib/slug-generator.js#L138)

Answer (score 1):

When using update methods in Mongoose, such as **Model.findByIdAndUpdate()**, the pre-save hook is not fired.

You will have to call the **save** method if you need the pre save hook to fire.

For example:

```
MyModel.findById(id, function(err, doc) {
    doc.name = 'new name';
    doc.save(function(err, doc) {
        // ...
    });
});
```